# SQL returning the wrong total

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this database:

[image: stock database]

And I have this sql: (both for Black and White)

```
SELECT 
    SUM(XS) AS TotalXS 
FROM 
    (SELECT XS 
     FROM `bng` 
     WHERE Color = 'White' 
       AND Action = 'Add' OR Action = 'Transfer Location' 

     UNION ALL 

     SELECT (XS*-1) AS GetXS 
     FROM `bng` 
     WHERE Color = 'White' AND Action = 'Used/ Damaged') AS FinalXS
```

My problem is: this SQL is returning the wrong total for "WHITE" only. See result below:

[image]

The result for `White` should be "13" for all columns. I've tried to find solutions but none of them would work for me. I want to also know if I have done anything wrong. Hope you guys could help me solve this one.

Comment: can you specify what are your variables for the summation?

Comment: let's say I have this formula:
x = addWhite
y = transWhite
z = getWhite

x+y-z=result

Comment: I tyhink you'd be better using a CASE statment on your actio to determine if you want to increment or decement the aggregate.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is missing brackets and (lack of) operator precedence in the first subquery:

```
WHERE Color = 'White' 
    AND Action = 'Add' OR Action = 'Transfer Location'
```

You probably wanted this to be

```
WHERE Color = 'White' 
    AND ( Action = 'Add' OR Action = 'Transfer Location' )
```

while the database interprets it as

```
WHERE ( Color = 'White' AND Action = 'Add' )
    OR Action = 'Transfer Location'
```

Comment: I'm sorry this is really confusing, this is the same code I used for "Black" which works fine

Comment: do you need to sum SM, etc. too?

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much @Jiri

Comment: It only works for 'Black' because there's no 'White' in state 'Transfer Location'. If you change the data to contain that, you'll see the code for 'Black' is broken as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT  COLOR, 
   SUM( CASE WHEN ACTION IN ('Add', 'Transfer Location') THEN XS ELSE -XS END ) AS SUM_XS
FROM BNG
WHERE ACTION IN  ('Add', 'Transfer Location', 'Used/ Damaged')
GROUP BY COLOR
```

Or another version (to avoid repeating case...):

```
SELECT COLOR
, SUM(XS*SIGN) AS SUM_XS
, SUM(SM*SIGN) AS SUM_SM
FROM (
    SELECT COLOR, XS, SM 
           , CASE WHEN ACTION IN ('Add', 'Transfer Location') THEN 1 ELSE -1 END AS SIGN   
    FROM BNG
     WHERE ACTION IN  ('Add', 'Transfer Location', 'Used/ Damaged')
    ) A
GROUP BY COLOR;
```

Comment: But @Jiri explain you well why your query didn't work.

Comment: @richelle : you know you can vote just one question?

Comment: no, sorry. I was trying to work on the answers that's why.

Comment: The important thing it's that you chose the answer that you think it's right for you (one and only one).  You can change your decision and mark the answer that you prefer (any one).